# How to embed a code editor in a website

Tags: embed, html, code-editor

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>ACE in Action</title>
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
    #editor { 
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="editor">function foo(items) {
    var x = "All this is syntax highlighted";
    return x;
}</div>

<script src="/ace-builds/src-noconflict/ace.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script>
    var editor = ace.edit("editor");
    editor.setTheme("ace/theme/monokai");
    editor.session.setMode("ace/mode/javascript");
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

i have tried ace code editor i've pasted the exact code on my web page but it is not working can u please help me out i want my editor be like same as w3school code editor.

Answer (score 3):

You don't seem to have `ace.js` in the path that you mentioned in the script src attribute.

Replace

```
<script src="/ace-builds/src-noconflict/ace.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

with

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ace/1.3.3/ace.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use cdn in the script or you can get the libraries in your local and try that script

`<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ace/1.3.3/ace.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>`

Comment: Can we compile code using Ace code editor?i beleive its a no but bit confused can someone help with answer